iOS How to use AWS Cognito Magic Link to authenticate the user
I need your help.
I need to implement AWS Cognito Magic Link to authenticate the user. I made in-app request to send an email. I do receive email with token. I parse it in the app. How to proceed with it and pass this token to sdk to authenticate the user.
I am doing the following:
- (void)authenticateUserWithToken:(NSString *)token {
    // Use the code to authenticate the user with AWS Cognito
    self.user = [self.userPool getUser:@"user@email.com"];//email on which token was sent
    self.token = token;
    
    [[self.user getSession] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType *> * _Nonnull task) {
        self.session = task.result;
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", self.session);
        return nil;
    }];
}

// AWSCognitoIdentityCustomAuthentication method
- (void)getCustomChallengeDetails:(AWSCognitoIdentityCustomAuthenticationInput *)authenticationInput customAuthCompletionSource:(AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityCustomChallengeDetails *> *)customAuthCompletionSource {
    if (self.user == nil || self.user.username == nil) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Create custom challenge details with the token and username
    AWSCognitoIdentityCustomChallengeDetails *authDetails = [[AWSCognitoIdentityCustomChallengeDetails alloc] initWithChallengeResponses:@{@"ANSWER" : self.token, @"USERNAME": self.user.username}];
    
    // Set the result for the custom authentication
    [customAuthCompletionSource setResult:authDetails];

    NSLog(@"Custom authentication details: %@", customAuthCompletionSource.task.result);
}
// Called when custom authentication step completes with or without an error
- (void)didCompleteCustomAuthenticationStepWithError:(NSError * _Nullable)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error during custom authentication: %@", error);
    }
}

As a result I have didCompleteCustomAuthenticationStepWithError called twice first time without error  and second time with error:

Error during custom authentication: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorDomain Code=21 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Incorrect username or password.}
After that continueWithBlock is called with the same error.
I am really lost whats happening and how to authenticate the user. Please help!

